# Chinese Chess online (Xiangqi)

Tags: chess-variants, xiangqi

I was curious about [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5191/tactical-difference-between-chess-and-chinese-chess), I watched two videos and learned a bit about Chinese Chess. Where can one play it online? What site has the biggest online Chinese chess community, where  you can play against computers or challenge other players.

It must be free and and must support westernized pieces because I can't read Chinese characters.

If the site has tutorials on the Chinese chess, it would be nice.

Comment: Learn to read the Chinese characters on the pieces.  It isn't hard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [PlayOK](http://www.playok.com/), it's free and has quite a lot of players for Xiangqi, and supports westernized pieces (though I'd recommend just learning the chinese characters, it doesn't take long). It also has some players for Shogi (japanese chess), which I personally find to be a much more interesting chess variant, though if you want to play more of that there are better sites (for example [81dojo](http://81dojo.com/)). For rules/tutorials, I guess the best place to start is simply the Xiangqi [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangqi).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [www.vietson.com](http://www.vietson.com).

You can also try [www.vietson.com](http://www.vietson.com). Variations of Chinese Chess are also available such as Dragon Chess, Shuffle Chess and Blind Chess

Answer (score 2):

PlayOK and Vietson, both are nothing for Beginners. Vietson is today the Strongest App to play Offline. while Online  PlayOK became very popular among skilled Chinese and Vietnamese , so it is too late for western players to join. As level of play is extremely high.
Graphics of PlayOK is excellent, except that the grid of lines showing rather rectangles instead of exact squares on the Board.
Another disadvantage is that it is too fast even for a skilled players at the end when suddenly everythings stops , and is gone , and a new game starting and you do not even understand if the other side won because you ran out of time, or did the opponent give Checkmate. Too late to see and understand even for skilled players.
Also Sounds sometimes work and sometimes not. Site Administrator usually does not respond to Questions or comments.
There is also www.chessvariants.org. But they use very old Computer Programs and their graphics are miserable.
If you have Java
Try Coffee Chinese Chess 0.6